# Set bone constraints via python API

Tags: python, scripting, armature, bones

Is there any way to add bone constraint through python api?
For example, I have two armatures:

```
armature1 = scene.objects['armature1']
armature2 = scene.objects['armature2']
```

Next, I select bone from each of armatures:

```
selected_bone = armature1.pose.bones["neck"]
target_bone = armature2.pose.bones["neck"]
```

And now I need to add a bone constraint for `selected_bone` to copy rotation of `target_bone`. Does python API have such method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a quick example adding a copy rotation constraint to the active pose bone (in your case `selected_bone`), and giving it as a target the pose bone "Bone" from armature object "Armature.001" (`target_bone`).  Notice you use the bone's name for a subtarget.

```
import bpy
#context & scene for testing
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

#active pose bone as example
bone = context.active_pose_bone
bone2 = None
# other armature other bone
arm2 = scene.objects.get("Armature.001")
if arm2 is not None:
    bone2 = arm2.pose.bones.get("Bone")
# give it a copy rotation constraint
if bone is not None:
    crc = bone.constraints.new('COPY_ROTATION')
    #give it a target bone
    crc.target = arm2
    # note subtarget uses name not object.
    crc.subtarget = bone2.name
```

Comment: what about getting constraints that a particular bone has?

Comment: All copy loc constraints on pose bone `bone` will be `[c for c in bone.constraints if c.type=='COPY_LOCATION']`

Comment: thanks a lot!! :-)