# Get list of attributes of a bpy.data struct?

Tags: python, scripting, data-blocks

Is there a way, in python, to get a list of each of the attributes that are part of a data struct? For example, I know you can get Object.data, Object.name, Object.location, etc. I've tried doing a basic for loop, but it says that the "object is not iterable."

Comment: Have you tried `dir(Object)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see 3 options :

- Looping through `object.bl_rna.properties.items()` (I think this is the preferred way since this is supported by the API)
- Looping through `dir(object)`, which is the python way so you might break things if you try to use these attributes if they are not exposed to `bl_rna`.
- Looking in the [official documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html), which at least gives examples and explanations about each attribute.

  ```
  import bpy

  obj = bpy.context.object    

  print('Using bl_rna :\n')

  for prop, value in obj.bl_rna.properties.items():

     print(prop, value)        

  print('\nUsing dir(object) :\n')

  for attr in dir(obj):

      print(str(attr), getattr(obj, attr))
  ```

[image]

etc.

[image]

etc.

Comment: That seems to work in general, but I can't figure out how to use it for this case: I'm adding a poseboneconstraint with constraint.new, which takes a (type) argument, and fails if you don't give it something on the type list. You can see the list in the documentation. I can do dir(constraint.new) and it tells me some stuff, but I can't figure out how to find the list of constraint names. See https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PoseBoneConstraints.html

Comment: I am not well versed in bone constraints, does this help ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46986/86891

Comment: That covers setting up the constraint and assigning various parameters of it. I've already got that working. I'm trying to figure out how to access a list of arguments/types that a command can accept in the python api. I'm just using the constraint as an example.

Comment: how would I only get the non-inherited properties?